# css - background-position: center center; makes image disapper

Tags: html, css

I am making a header with a background-image that i want to center so i add background-position: center center; But with it, the image just disappear, if i remove the background-position: center center; everything works fine. How should i fix this because i don't see any error in Chrome Console.

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header class="header">
        </header>
    </div>
</body>

.header {
    min-height: 80rem;
    background-image: url("../images/bg-header.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: CSS errors wont show up in the Chrome Console, by default.

Answer (score 1):

Using `background-size: cover` will enlarge the image until the entire div is full.

Try using `background-size: contain`. This will display your image inside the container and allowing you to center it.

```
.header {
    background-image: url("../images/bg-header.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: contain;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`background-size: cover;` will crop the image if needed. All that it plans to do is fill the entire page regardless if the whole image fits in the page or not.

`background-size: contain;` makes sure that the entire image is shown on the page regardless if it is large enough to fill the whole page or not.